# How to go from settings menu back to app? (Swift IOS 10)

Tags: swift, settings, ios10

I have created an SMS app in Xcode (Swift). The user will go to the app's settings menu by pressing a button.

Here is the code for the button:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) as! URL, options:[:], completionHandler: nil)
```

There I can write the phone number and it will be linked to my app. But when I am in my settings menu I would like to go back to my app. Now it will only go back to the normal settings menu. Is this possible? I have tried looking but it's hard to find something when iOS 10 is new. I have just recently started coding on iPhone apps.

Comment: Is the viewcontroller in a navigation controller? If so, it should just let you go back to the app by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing you can do in your own app. The call to `open` launches another app and leaves your app.

iOS provides two simple ways for the user to return to your app.

- In the top left corner of the iOS screen will be a little arrow and the name of your app. If the user taps on this, they will be returned to your app.
- The user can double-tap the Home button to bring up the list of recently used apps. They can then tap on your app's icon to return to your app.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the info! :) I tried to spare some time using the settings menu. but i will create my own instead. :) .